# Read and rename a file from a folder in C

Tags: c

I want to make a program that reads the name of a (.mp3) file from a folder and then re-name it. I want to know how to do so.

Please give me an example on how to read a (.mp3) file name and save it, and also point to me things that I should know to make this program.

I'm on windows and using VS2013.

Comment: Do you mean, something like this ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w05844e.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You might like to use the [`rename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx) function.

To scan a directory you can use a combination of [FindFirstFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) calls.

Comment: While the _hint_ is correct, the __answer__ is perhaps of little use to the OP.  You might to post the complete working code, instead.

Comment: @denull: Yes sure! ;-)